# Is it possible to implement Peterson's algorithms for 3 processes and more?

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing

So one of my assistive instructors at school gave us this assignment of implementing Peterson's algorithms for 3 processes along with some other assignments. I thought it would be doable having known how it works for 2 threads, but it wasn't and also so hard to check where it was failing because of the nature of multi-processing. I googled and found there are Filter's algorithm and Bakery algorithm that can work for N-processes but those don't look straight out of Peterson's algorithms. The instructor said he didn't check the validity of his question and seeing how I can't really find relevant code on this vast Google ocean I'm becoming dubious if I'm even doing things that can be done..!

Thank you for any help and forgive if there was wrong grammar, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: `I googled and found there are Filter's algorithm and Bakery algorithm that can work for N-processes but those don't look straight out of Peterson's algorithms.` - Verdict "don't look" is quite.. **subjective**. For *adapt* an algorithm for work in conditions, in which it doesn't work initially, you should **modify** the algorithm. If you want to discard algorithms, which differs from original "too much" you should define that "too much" in more **objective** terms. BTW, [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm) treats Filter algorithm as extension of Peterson's one.

Comment: Wikipedia says that Filter algorithm is an extension of Peterson's algorithm for N processors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm#Filter_algorithm:_Peterson's_algorithm_for_more_than_two_processes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension to the Peterson's algorithm is Filter algorithm, just go ahead. This can be done.